# .htaccess redirect excluding sub-domains

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

I have the following in my .htaccess to redirect all old domain names which point to the same location to the new domain, but this doesn't allow any sub domains of the new domain name to work - any idea how to amend the code to allow sub-domains would be appreciated:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.newdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Redirect subdomain to subdomain under a new domain...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: sorry, but I don't think I've made myself very clear - I have several domains which point to this specific new domain. All of them are automatically redirected to www.newdomain.com - and I want it to be with www. - but it also redirects all sub-domains of this new domain to the main domain. Therefore none of the suggested solutions will work for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Brian - it certainly helped - the final outcome is the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.newdomain\.com$ [NC] [AND]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)\.newdomain\.com$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks for your time.